# How to check if computer is in the given Active Directory folder

Tags: windows, search, active-directory

At my company we have over 200 PCs that are allocated in different folders inside Active Directory.

Lately there has been lots of computer changes and right now the AD is quite a mess. Computers are misplaced in wrong folders.

I have a list of all the computers being used. I am using the Windows program: *Active Directory Users and Computers*, to monitor the directories.

I want to put the computers into the appropriate directory where they should be.

Right now, I can search inside a folder for a given computer after its name.

My question: Is there a way to search for all of the computers from my list, to check if it is in the right directory?

example:

Lets say we have 2 folders in the AD:

`Folder1` and `Folder2`

We have 3 PCs:

`PC1`, `PC2`, `PC3`

`PC1` and `PC2` are in `Folder1`
`PC3` is in `Folder2`

I want to search for all PCs in `Folder1` and get the result that `PC3` is not in it.

> Note: I have an excel list with the computer names. The best solution would be a VBA script that checks this (I just need the function, I can code the rest), but I accept other solutions as well.

Answer (score 2):

To take a list of computers in a text file and get their OU here is one way to do it in PowerShell

```
$Computers = Get-Content C:\Computers.txt
Foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $TempOU = ((Get-ADComputer $Computer).DistinguishedName
    Write-Host "$Computer is in $TempOU"
}
```

This assumes you have a text file and each line is a separate computer name.

Comment: yes, I meant OUs, just used 'folders' for easier understanding for my example. I am not really familiar with PowerShell, could You do some explanation what happens in the script?

Comment: @Divin3 Sorry missed your comment. It searches a given OU for all computers and lists their account name.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, this is not what I need. I have to check all computers from a list, if they are in the right OU.

Comment: @Divin3 Check my answer now.

Comment: This what I am looking for, I will try it as soon as I can and give a feedback